# Telegram bot web apps geolocation permission

Tags: reactjs, geolocation, bots, telegram, telegram-bot

I created a telegram web app bot in react, it asks permission from user to get current geolocation of him. But once user blocks this permission, bot can never detect current location. My question is, how can user unblock this bot from location permissions?

I tried to ask user permission, but once user blocked, bot can not send request to detect current location.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same but with **svelte** with the same results. When allow, I get the geolocation, but when deny, it is impossible to reset the permission, because **WebApp** uses device browser. The only way to get a prompt again is to set in the device browser, but in iPhone I can't found the setting.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Permissions_API/Using_the_Permissions_API